# Converting String to datetime (from Week number/Year to dd/mm/yy) in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, date-formatting

I have the following `DataFrame`

```
example = {"Time":["01/2021","02/2021","04/2021","05/2021"]}
df = pd.DataFrame( example )


    Time
0   01/2021
1   02/2021
2   04/2021
3   05/2021
```

Column `Time` is composed by `string`s.
Each `string` is composed by week number (from 1 to 52) and Year.

I would like to convert to dd/mm/yyyy

```
    Time    Time Converted 
0   01/2021  10/01/2021
1   02/2021  17/01/2021
2   04/2021  24/01/2021
3   05/2021  31/01/2021
```

1. How can I do that?
2. How to chose the dd if it should be Monday or Sunday? Like in the following alternative output?

   ```
        Time    Time Converted 
   0    01/2021  04/01/2021
   1    02/2021  11/01/2021
   2    04/2021  18/01/2021
   3    05/2021  25/01/2021
   ```

I tried to find any other question specifically dealing with the week number, but I couldn't find it.

If this is a duplicate please let me know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df['Time Converted'] = pd.to_datetime('1/' + df['Time'], format='%w/%U/%Y')
print(df)

# Output
      Time Time Converted
0  01/2021     2021-01-04
1  02/2021     2021-01-11
2  04/2021     2021-01-25
3  05/2021     2021-02-01
```

- `%w`: Weekday number
- `%U`: Week number of the year
- `%Y`: Year

**Update**

> I would like to get the last day of the week and not Monday. (e.g. 10/01/2021 instead of 04/01/2021).

```
df['Time Converted'] = pd.to_datetime('0/' + df['Time'], format='%w/%U/%Y') \
                       + pd.DateOffset(days=7)
print(df)

# Output
      Time Time Converted
0  01/2021     2021-01-10
1  02/2021     2021-01-17
2  04/2021     2021-01-31
3  05/2021     2021-02-07
```

Note: adjust the day of the week (0, 1 or 6) according to your `locale`.

Comment: thank you! If I would like to get the last day of the week and not Monday? (e.g. 10/01/2021 instead of 04/01/2021) ?

Comment: @AndreaCiufo. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?